# Odd dead pixels in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

For some time now, I've had some odd "dead" pixels at the very top of my display (the white may be hard to see, view the image at imgur):

[image]

I use two monitors, one 1920x1200 and another 1920x1080. The odd thing is that when I move the top bar to one display or the other, the white disappears on the display with the top bar and appears on the other. Here's some information about my machine:

- Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2 LTS
- Dual monitor:

  1. Apple Display, 1920x1200, connected via DVI (GPU)
  2. Samsung Flatron, 1920x1080, connected via DisplayPort (GPU) to HDMI (Display)
- An AMD R9 270X graphics card

This issue's been persistent even before I switched monitors so it doesn't seem to be a monitor issue. It may have showed up when I updated Ubuntu, but it wasn't present when I used 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Looks like a background image (sky at night), there is even something written in the top right of your image, I cant read it, it's to small. May this give you a hint.

Comment: @mook765 I'll look into it. I'm currently away from the computer, but I think I've tried changing the background before and it persisted, but I will check again later. Thanks for the tip.